# FFT convolution question

Tags: fft, filters

Designing a signal filter - I'm trying to understand how it is possible to take the FFT of a filter kernel and multiply it by the FFT of the signal to provide signal filtering as surely the FFT of the signal needs to be filtered with a low pass filter first to avoid aliasing.

So it seems a rather chicken and egg arrangement? I want a filter, but in order to get the signal to be filtered the signal used in the filter itself needs to have been filtered?

Answer (score 1):

Frequency domain aliasing is mostly only a problem when converting from the continuous time domain to the discrete time domain:

$$
x[n] = x(nT_s)
$$

where $T_s$ is the sampling period.

To avoid aliasing, it's generally advisable to low-pass filter $x(t)$ in the continuous time domain before sampling it.

Once you have $x[n]$ there is no more need to worry about aliasing if you are just doing linear filtering.

If you perform nonlinear operations in the discrete time domain, then there may be more aliasing problems, but that doesn't seem to be the case you're talking about.

The other aliasing that comes into play is time aliasing.  Here, an FFT of length $N$ is used to perform circular convolution.  So if your signal is length $M$ and your filter is of length $L$, then you must ensure that $$N \ge M + L - 1$$

to avoid time domain aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: I've just succeeded in getting a FFT (512) samples running on a microprocessor (in assembler) to sample sound signals. I was hoping to apply a filter kernel to filter out high frequency but I conclude from your reply that I will need to apply some sort of low pass filter to the sound signal before sampling it for the FFT?

Comment: What do you mean by "*sampling it for the FFT*"? You don't need to worry about low-pass filtering if you're working with a digital signal , i.e a signal that has already gone through an ADC and is now in digital form.